# How to set iframe height dynamically before pressing the button which show it? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I inserted an iframe element() on the page and dynamically recognize its height via a subscription to the event
and install it dynamically. iframe appears and after a few seconds its true height is set.
How to make it so that you first download the iframe, then set its height, and then click on the button to show it. And in this case we have an iframe with true height at once

Comment: Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates 
your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Comment: do it all in an `onload` callback.